# Shell script for creating kerberos keytab

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, kerberos

I am trying to develop a shell script to generate keytab using ktutil. I need to add two principals to the keytab. Two principals are not unique. First principal should be added with password flag and second principal should be added with the key flag ( key will be obtained from first principal). Since ktutil doesn't allow string operations, I am generating temp keytab with first principal and extracting key from it by reading keytab and assigned key to variable *key* as in below script

In the below script, I am able to add principal with password flag, but not with the key flag. execution stuck at prompting hex key, it is not picking from the input variable provided in the script. If any invalid key is provided, it is throwing error as "illegal characters in the key". Wondering why it is not moving to the next step with valid key. I am unable to use expect in script since I am doing this in corporate env.

### **Script**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    user1="PRINCIPAL1"
    pass="topsecret"
    user2="PRINCIPAL2"
        
    printf "%b" "addent -password -p $user1 -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96\n$pass\nwrite_kt temp.keytab" | ktutil

    tmp=`printf "%b" "read_kt temp.keytab\nlist -k\nexit" | ktutil`
    key=`echo $tmp | awk '{print substr($10, 3, length($10) - 1)}'`
        
    printf "%b" "addent -key -p $user2 -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96\n$key\nwrite_kt $user.keytab" | ktutil
```

**working command:**

`printf "%b" "addent -password -p $user1 -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96\n$pass\nwrite_kt temp.keytab" | ktutil`

**Not working:**

`printf "%b" "addent -key -p $user2 -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96\n$key\nwrite_kt $user.keytab" | ktutil`

> It is generating keytab with the name temp.keytab. But, not generating
> keytab with name PRINCIPAL.keytab. instead, it is getting stuck at
> prompting for hex key in output

Comment: Wait, why are you doing this at all? Why not just... use the first keytab directly? It has the same principal and the same key, after all.

Comment: @user1686 those two principals are different and I want to add the second principal using key obtained from the first principal and I forgot to mention the same in the question. I just edited post now. please check. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The result of `printf "%b" "read_kt temp.keytab\nlist -k\nexit"` is empty. There is no 10th column in any of the result rows, you should check the output manually.

The Principal key is listed in the 5th row and 4rd column in parenthesis, I'm not sure if `awk '{print substr($10, 3, length($10) - 1)}'` will extract it properly.